Azure Universal Printing Issue
I have registered my printing using the universal print connector tool. I can see it in the universal print azure console but the status is just blank. When I share it out it is also not visible to users. I added two other printers though with no problems.
I have no idea why its not working.
I updated the firmware and unregistered and reregistered it multiple times and that did not help either.
Thanks!
Example
